# Android speech recognition limited to a set of strings

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I am trying to implement voice recognition in Android. I have followed various tutorials for the same which say, we need to give call to `RecognizerIntent` with `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` and start activity for result. So when we speak,we get a set of values from the google server by providing `RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS`. This is working fine. But what I need to do is, I need to provide a set of strings to the voice recognition engine, so when we say something, it will match what we have said with the provided set of strings and returns only one matched string.So I need to provide the recognizer engine some set of values from which it should give me the matched word. Can this be done?

Comment: github.com/lukasolson/speech-router

Comment: See this answer for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557970/voice-control-api-high-accuracy-on-specific-phrases/12573707#12573707

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with pocketsphinx, see keyword matching mode in tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid